# How do I save a procedurally-generated map as binary level-data in C++?

Tags: c++, procedural-generation, savegame

For example, I'd like to do something as simple as a generating an array matrix using Conway's Game of Life and then filling each cell with particular data to be saved to a binary file.

Additionally, how do I load the binary level-data?  :)

Comment: Quick questions: how long does it take to generate the map? And is the map altered somehow during play-time?

Comment: First you generate the data, then you save it. What *specifically* are you having trouble with? What have you tried? File IO in general is not a game-development specific problem.

Answer (score 4):

If the data's small, just use a text format like XML, JSON, CSV, or your own flavour. If OTOH the data is massive and/or private and/or size / parse speed important, then binary's probably best.

You will need to create a binary data format / layout to be used. This would denote a byte array of a certain size and which bits therein are used for what, e.g you might have a `struct` of 64 bits where 4 bits act as one field and the other 60 as another field. This is a very simple example; you will more likely have several, nested struct types representing the full body of data for a more complex game. Now use an output `stream` to save this to disk or send it over the network, or alternatively use your own custom in-game protocol to do same.

As for restoring from that save, you'd likely parse back into the same `struct` type after retrieving the `stream` (byte array) from disk or network: get the `stream` contents with the correct endianness, and then static-cast its data to the `struct` type in question (this doesn't take into account `struct` padding bytes which may / may not be stripped on initial conversion to a stream).

Comment: Thanks for the response!  The ladder two paragraphs went a little over my head, so it might be best for me to begin with a text format.  Should I look into something like how to serialize arrays of structs?

Comment: @Cuppasoup Honestly, if you have no pressing need, use XML. Otherwise it's really just a matter of knowing the language you've tagged this question with - which is assumed or else you should be doing some research (3 others have voted to close because you haven't done your research before asking.)

Answer (score 2):

If the data is a simple array and it's just for a personal project you could do something as straight-forward as read and write each array element to/from a file. Flatten the matrix into a 1-D array, and just make sure that you read the elements from the file in the same order that you wrote them. If, on the other hand, you want to serialise something more complicated than an array of primitives then you could look into using something like [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/).

For an example of the first approach:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    // initalise a collection with data for writing, here
    // we are just using integers for simplicity.
    int array[] = {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0};
    // if using C++11 you could use an initializer list
    // to construct the vector, e.g:
    //  std::vector<int> outVector = {1, 0, 1, 1, ...}
    std::vector<int> out_vector(array, array + sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array));

    // define the input/output filename. if you need to manipulate
    // the filename at all, use a std::string instead of char*.
    char *file_name = "example";

    // declare a file stream to read/write data to the file
    std::fstream f;
    // open the file for writing, and proceed to write
    // each integer to the file.
    f.open(file_name, std::fstream::out);
    for (size_t i; i < out_vector.size(); i++) {
        f << out_vector[i];
    }
    f.close();

    // initialise a collection for reading the data back in
    std::vector<int> in_vector;
    // open the file for reading, and proceed to read
    // each character of the file into the new collection.
    f.open(file_name, std::fstream::in);

    char in_char;
    while (f >> in_char) {
        int in_int = in_char - '0'; // convert char -> int
        in_vector.push_back(in_int);
    }
    f.close();

    // the collections should contain the same data
    assert(in_vector == out_vector);
}
```